# Inject JMockit mocks into Spring context

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, jmockit

For some integration tests, we use Spring’s `@ContextConfiguration` to create a real Spring context during the test. Now, it’s not supposed to be a full integration test, so we need a whole bunch of the Spring beans as mocks. This is not too complicated using Mockito and Spring’s factory-method, and even easier with [Springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home).

But, this is using [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito), while we are just migrating to [JMockit](http://jmockit.org/). I would much prefer to use JMockit here as well. Basically, I am looking for a replacement for Springockito that uses JMockit instead.

I can also do it by hand. However, Mockito and JMockit seem to differ in one very important way: While in Mockito, you create mocks imperatively using a call to a method, in JMockit you get mocks declaratively ‘injected’ into your test. That’s too late to populate the Spring context. So if anyone can answer that, I’m happy as well: How can you create a mock in JMockit *in your code*?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Test to do all the injection, then you can just let it do the job of creating instances for all dependencies, while having them mocked through suitable mock fields/parameters declared with the `@Mocked` or `@Capturing` annotations. The latter one will mock any implementation class that Spring has chosen to instantiate, even though the type used in the mock declaration is an interface or base class.

Alternatively, you could just let JMockit itself resolve all dependencies, by using `@Tested(fullyInitialized = true)` for top-level tested objects, with mocked dependencies provided as `@Injectable`'s.

Comment: That does not work. Spring creates the context _before_ JMockit kicks in and overwrites the constructors.

Comment: As for using `fullyInitialized` – that’s certainly the right thing to do when all you want from Spring is the DI, but in my test I need the web app configuration to test the MCV controllers.

Comment: Why does it matter if Spring creates beans before they are mocked? Do they execute some code that fails or something?

Comment: Bean initialized by Spring may execute code in `@PostConstruct`, and they are a target for autowiring as well (they need _their_ dependencies to exist).

Comment: Yes, indeed. That *could* be a problem, if you need dependencies used in a `@PostConstruct` to be mocked; in practice, that should be very rare, though.

Answer (score 0):

A "dirty" trick we use with Spring and Integration Tests while we still need to mock something, is to replace - where required - the real configuration, e.g.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("!test")
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyBean bean() {
        /** Real bean **/
    }
}
```

with a mock one

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class MyTestConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyBean bean() {
        final MyBean bean = mock(MyBean.class);
        when(bean.doSomething()).thenReturn(withReply());
        return bean;
    }
}
```

it works with a "real" Spring Integration Test context and Mockito, it should work with JMockit as well, as long as you are able to create your bean with JMockit version of your class: basically something equivalent to *mock(MyBean.class)*.

Edit: Whilst I am not familiar with JMockit, it seems that an equivalent way could be

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class MyTestConfig {

    @Injectable MyBean mockXyz;

    @Bean
    public MyBean bean() {
        /** You can probably mock its behaviour **/
        return mockXyz;
    }
}
```

Comment: For me it seems there really is no equivalent for `mock(MyBean.class)` in JMockit.

Comment: Even though a test class can be its own configuration class in a Spring test (which looks mind-boggling), at that point in time JMockit has not yet kicked in. In other words, the `@Injectable` annotation has not yet had any effect, `mockXyz` is `null`.